# Creating a Procedure MySQL

Tags: mysql

Im trying to convert a procedure from using sql plus to mysql but am getting a syntax error on the third line where it says (W_IN IN NUMBER) and it has IN highlighted as the syntax error.

SQL Plus:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE PRC_CUS_BALANCE_UPDATE (W_IN IN NUMBER) AS
W_CUS NUMBER := 0;
W_TOT NUMBER := 0;
BEGIN
-- GET THE CUS_CODE
SELECT CUS_CODE INTO W_CUS 
FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = W_IN;

-- UPDATES CUSTOMER IF W_CUS > 0
IF W_CUS > 0 THEN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE + 
                (SELECT INV_TOTAL FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_NUMBER = W_IN)
    WHERE CUS_CODE = W_CUS;
END IF;
END;
```

mySQL:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_cus_balance_update (W_IN IN NUMBER) 
AS
W_CUS NUMBER = 0;
W_TOT NUMBER = 0;
BEGIN
-- GET CUS_CODE
SELECT CUS_CODE INTO W_CUS 
FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = W_IN;

-- UPDATES CUSTOMER IF W_CUS > 0
IF W_CUS > 0 THEN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE + 
                (SELECT INV_TOTAL FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_NUMBER = W_IN)
    WHERE CUS_CODE = W_CUS;
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This compiles in MySQL 5.5.23:

```
-- Trigger DDL Statements
DELIMITER $$

DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS prc_cus_balance_update;

CREATE PROCEDURE prc_cus_balance_update (IN W_IN INT UNSIGNED) 
BEGIN
DECLARE W_CUS INT UNSIGNED DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE W_TOT DOUBLE DEFAULT 0; -- NOT USED?
-- GET CUS_CODE
SELECT CUS_CODE INTO W_CUS 
FROM INVOICE
WHERE INVOICE.INV_NUMBER = W_IN;

-- UPDATES CUSTOMER IF W_CUS > 0
IF W_CUS > 0 THEN
    UPDATE CUSTOMER
    SET CUS_BALANCE = CUS_BALANCE + 
                (SELECT INV_TOTAL FROM INVOICE WHERE INV_NUMBER = W_IN)
    WHERE CUS_CODE = W_CUS;
END IF;
END $$

DELIMITER ;
```

Of course, in this case, a stored procedure is not needed, as the following query will perform the same function much faster (and easier to understand):

```
UPDATE 
    CUSTOMER c
INNER JOIN
    INVOICE i ON i.CUS_CODE = c.CUS_CODE
SET 
    c.CUS_BALANCE = c.CUS_BALANCE + i.INV_TOTAL 
WHERE 
    i.INV_NUMBER = W_IN
```

Comment: After you assigned $$ as delimiter, you have to put that as statement end for Drop

Comment: @Ross Smith II can you help me with my [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62611169/how-to-write-procedure-to-fetch-data-from-other-table?noredirect=1#comment110722972_62611169)

Answer (score 2):

The doc seems to say

```
 [ IN | OUT | INOUT ] param_name type
```