# Sql Query used to xtract data embedded with php

Tags: mysql, sql, select, group-by, sum

My Table: **performance**

```
--------------------------
Name   |  Year |  Value  |
--------------------------
John   |  1999 |   100   |
--------------------------
Collin |  2000 |   125   |
--------------------------
John   |  2001 |   150   |
--------------------------
John   |  2000 |   100   |
--------------------------
John   |  2001 |   150   |
--------------------------
Collin |  2003 |   500   | 
--------------------------
```

what i all want is to get the o/p as below.

```
-------------------------------------------
Name  |   1999   |  2000 |  2001  |  2003   |
-------------------------------------------
John  |   100    |  100  |  300   | (NULL)  |
-------------------------------------------
Collin|  (NULL)  |  125  | (NULL) |  500    |
-------------------------------------------
```

more info: John didnt perform well in 2003 so its value is `NULL` n so on.n in respective years value is summed.
I jst want sql query for the above pbm,m done with all connections with php.treate as simple sql query n assist me..

Thanx..

Comment: write a stored procedure to get the results

Comment: there are more years?

Comment: ya actually its undefined..any no.of years n any no. of names,,so in general would b better solution..thanxx

Answer (score 3):

I don't think you can have a dynamic number of columns depending on your query result. That's why I suggest having the result like:

```
Name    Year    Sum
Collin  1999    (NULL)
Collin  2000    125
Collin  2001    (NULL)
Collin  2003    500
John    1999    100
John    2000    100
John    2001    300
John    2003    (NULL)
```

You can do this using GROUP BY. To get NULLs, use CROSS JOIN between all names and all years from the table.

```
SELECT performance_names.Name, performance_years.Year, SUM(p.Value) AS Sum
FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT P.Name
FROM performance AS P) AS performance_names
CROSS JOIN
(SELECT DISTINCT P.Year
FROM performance AS P) AS performance_years
LEFT JOIN performance AS p
ON performance_names.`Name` = p.`Name` AND p.`Year` = performance_years.`Year`
GROUP BY performance_names.`Name`, performance_years.`Year`
```

Comment: thats get the output values but formated in rows? He asked (if he know what he whant) to get them in columns format.

Comment: That's right, Melon. But what he asked is not mysql-ish. That's why I suggested something easier, maybe it'll be enough for what he needs.

Comment: thats absolutely true. I just wanted to notice a posible diference (for future visitors), but your code works perfect.

Comment: @mimarcel: names cnt b repeated,jst want 2 names n their values in corresponding years..dats wat i want.n even in que i mentioned dat wat o/p i want..

Comment: @user3172177 If that's what you want, then use Saharsh Shah's idea. I added a [comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20989842/sql-query-used-to-xtract-data-embedded-with-php/20991250?noredirect=1#comment31545148_20989981) there.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
SELECT p.Name, 
       SUM(IF(p.year = 1999, p.value, 0)) AS `1999`, 
       SUM(IF(p.year = 2000, p.value, 0)) AS `2000`, 
       SUM(IF(p.year = 2001, p.value, 0)) AS `2001`, 
       SUM(IF(p.year = 2003, p.value, 0)) AS `2003`
FROM performance p 
GROUP BY p.Name;
```

Comment: thats work perfect if only these years exist. (or if the years in DB are fixed)

Comment: @user3172177 What is the problem?

Comment: @SaharshShah what happend if u got year 2002? or 2013? this didnt work. (unles u remake the select with each year and u modify it each time a new year income)

Comment: @vipul. o/p of ur solution: AB,,dats it..

Comment: If that's what you want then you will have to add the years you want/might have manually in the query (let's say 1900 to 2200), but that will result in a huge query. It's the only solution I see.

I'd suggest you to automatically generate your query writing some code in any programming language. E.g., running this php would give you the query:
    $s = "SELECT p.Name,";
    for ($i = 1900; $i <= 2200; $i++) {
     $s .= "\nSUM(IF(p.year = $i, p.value, 0)) AS `$i`";
     if ($i < 2200) {
      $s .= ",";
     }
    }
    $s .= "\nFROM performance p\nGROUP BY p.Name;";
    echo $s;

Answer (score 0):

You shuld create a stored procedure that store your desired values in another table,

just some hints, in your stored procedure you shuld (by order):

1. Concatenate all years as string in a variable
2. Use this variable to create the table
3. loop with a cursor over your original table and increment the columns of the select user
4. After your procedure call just select all values of your created table

if u dont know how to create a procedure you can take a look [-->Here<--](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12755003/creating-a-procedure-mysql)